# Python pillow module not importing properly

Tags: python-imaging-library

I'm using the Python pillow module, but every time I try to import it and use a function, it gives me an error. Here is some code to reproduce the error.

```
import PIL

PIL.ImageGrab.grab()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `from` to import from PIL.

```
from PIL import ImageGrab

ImageGrab.grab()
```